# JSON String to Object - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In my controller I have a 'show' action and inside of it is an instance variable like:

`@resume = Resume.find(params[:id])`

It grabs the appropriate information from the database and displays that specific resume on the "show" page.

One of the fields is a string called "content" with a json object inside.

I want to know how to turn that @resume.content from a json string into an object so I can loop through it on the show page template.

Sorry if this question was not constructed properly, please ask if you need further explanation.

Comment: Can you post the actual value inside the `content` attribute?  And also the string that's returned when you do `content.to_json`?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `@resume.content.to_json` ?

Comment: based on the fact that they have a show action in their resume controller, I think it's safe to say they are using rails

Comment: Ok I just tried that and it's converting it into a json string so i set it to a variable and tried parsing the variable. This is currently what's in my resumes/show action -> (at)resume = Resume.find(params[:id])

    str = (at)resume.content.to_json
    (at)resumeContent = JSON.parse(str)

Answer (score 4):

To parse a string to Ruby object

```
JSON.parse @resume.content
```